# API inside child dynamic component doesn't fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an api (photoFetch) that fetches a JSON that holds photo data from an online JSONplaceholder. It is located inside my child component, that is a dynamic component based on id (the parent component is my home page)

userPhotoPage.js (child component)

```
export const UserPhotoPage = async ({match}) => {
const [data, setData] = useState("");

const photoFetch = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => setData(data.albums))
        .catch(error => console.log("error"))

const userPhoto = photoFetch.find((userPhoto) =>{
    return parseInt(match.params.id) == userPhoto.id
})

return <>
    {match.isExact && <>
        <h1>{userPhoto.title}</h1>
        <p>image = {userPhoto.url}</p>
        </>}
    </>
}
```

I also tried wrapping it in a try catch statement, but nothing works. It doesn't fetch data and I always get a "(TypeError): Cannot read property 'find' of undefined" because my const userPhoto isn't fetching any data from photoFetch.find((userPhoto). I'm new to REACT so I don't really know how to proceed to fixing this. Have been working on this for a while now.

I am able to fetch data with a user JSON on my parent component (home page), and I use a very similar method. I am trying to recreate it for my child component but it doesn't work. This is how it looks like on the home page. (I'm only posting a snippet of the code here, the top portion)

homePage.js (parent component, just an example)

```
class homePage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        users: [],
        isLoading: false,
        search: ""
    };
}
async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => this.setState({users: result}))
        .catch(error => console.log("error"))
}
```

Thank you again stack overflow for helping out a noob like me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must not have a direct fetch request in the functional component body, instead you must use `useEffect` hook.

Secondly, instead of getting the data and then filtering on id, you can simply request `/photos/:id`

Lastly, the data returned is an array and doesn't contains albums key

You code will look like

```
export const UserPhotoPage = async ({match}) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
       await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/${match.params.id}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => setData(result))
            .catch(error => console.log("error"))

    }, [match.params.id])


    return <>
        {match.isExact && <>
            <h1>{data.title}</h1>
            <p>image = {data.url}</p>
            </>}
        </>

}
```

Comment: This works, but i'm still not getting any data for some reason. it says it is "null" inside of my data after fetching the data in useEffect :(

Comment: @alicenwondurland Its because there was a typo. State must be set like`.then(result => setData(result))`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `const photoFetch = await (...)` your code awaits to get the result of the promise and sets the const's value with it. However, your promise is not returning anything, because the body of the last `.then()` executes a void operation that just changes the value of the hook "data" by calling `setData(...)`. That's why your error says Cannot read property 'find' of undefined": photoFind does not have an assigned value at that point.
You should return a value in the arrow function of the last `.then()` in order to set that value to the constant. (I do not know the API you are using so I am unsure what this value should be. Maybe your userPhoto is trying to search for a value in your hook called data?)

P.D: I would also suggest you to remember setting the value of `isLoading` to false again when the result is fetched or an error is catched in the method `ComponentDidMount` of your homePage!

Answer (score 1):

React introduces hooks in version 16.8 which can be use in our functional components we have a hook called `useEffect` to call apis or any asynchronous call which we used to call in our `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`. So your child component will look something like this.
Also we don't need to `.then` when we are using `async-await`.

```js
export const UserPhotoPage = async ({match}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          setData(data.albums)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log("error"))

  }
  const userPhoto = photoFetch.find((userPhoto) =>{
    return parseInt(match.params.id) == userPhoto.id
  })

  return (<>
    {match.isExact && <>
        <h1>{userPhoto.title}</h1>
        <p>image = {userPhoto.url}</p>
        </>}
    </>)
}
```

Please have a read [using useEffect Effectively](https://dev.to/mkamranhamid/using-useeffect-effectively-2722)

Comment: This does, but i'm still not getting any data for some reason. it says it is "null" inside of my data after fetching the data in useEffect :(

Comment: Yes because the API you are using returns an array and you're expecting an object `data.title`. You will have to loop through the array using `.map`